# If a problem A has a poly-time reduction to a problem B in co-NP, is A in co-NP as well?

Tags: np, polynomial-time-reductions, co-np

i.e. $A\leq_pB\:\wedge\:B\in\text{co-NP}\rightarrow A\in\text{co-NP}$ ?

I feel like it's the case but I can't think of a straightforward proof.

Clarification: I am talking about polynomial-time Turing reductions.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this with coNP replaced by NP? If so, try connecting the two.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It seems not. I know there are a few questions about this here but none of the answers make sense to me. For example, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/128187/if-x-is-polynomial-reduction-to-y-and-y-is-in-np-then-x-is-in-np here there only seems to be a question of a 1-to-1 reduction. But a polynomial-time reduction can have multiple calls to problem B, not only one.

Comment: Are you sure the reduction is not many-one?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What do you mean? In that problem? It says the reduction is "x in X iff phi(x) in Y", that's a single call to Y, isn't it?

Comment: So the reduction in your case is many-one. You mentioned that "a polynomial-time reduction can have multiple calls to problem B", but this is not the case here.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Is that what many-one means? I'm not sure about this. If you solve problem A with 10 calls to problem B for example, is that many-one?

Comment: No. A many-one reduction is a function $\phi$ as in your preceding comment.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Ok. So I am talking about a polynomial-time Turing reduction. How do you prove that if a problem A reduces to a problem in NP, then that problem A is in NP? I can't see a solution because of the non-determinism of turing machines which solve NP problems.

Comment: Your reduction is not a Turing reduction. It’s a many-one reduction.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus But I meant Turing reductions. That is what my question was about. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Any problem Turing-reduces to its complement, so your question is essentially equivalent to NP=coNP.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus which is an open question. Interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus But how do you prove that statement but with NP instead of coNP? It that feasible? If a problem A poly-time turing reduces to a problem B in NP, is A in NP?

Comment: The statements for NP and coNP are equivalent. Either both hold or both don't.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thank you.