# if X is in NP but Y is not in NP then can X be reduced to Y?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np, decision-problem

I have been led to believe that the following statement

$X \in NP \land Y \not\in NP \implies X \not\le^m_p Y$

Is True.

But I am having difficult proving it. And I'm not even sure it IS true anymore.

At first it seemed reasonable that it was true. Since X is in NP there must exist some NP-complete problem Z that it reduces to and my thinking is that any other problem that X reduces to must also reduce to this NP-complete problem Z, that is, since X is in NP both it and any problem it can be reduced to must also reduce to an NP-complete problem Z so it cannot be the case that X can be reduced to a problem Y that is NOT in NP. This is not my proof but simply my intuition for why the statement is True.

I was hoping initially to prove it by contradiction:

> suppose not, that is, suppose $X \in NP \land Y \not\in NP$ but $X \le^m_p Y$
>
> since $X \in NP$ it must be that $\exists$ a poly-time verifier algorithm $B$ such that
> $\forall$ inputs $x \in X$ : $\exists$ certificate $t$ s.t. $B(x,t) = yes$
>
> and since $X \le^m_p Y$ it must be that $\exists$ a poly-time reduction $f$ such that
> $\forall$ inputs $x$ $x \in X \iff f(x) \in Y$
>
> it follows then that $f(x) \in Y \iff x \in X \iff \exists t B(x,t) = yes$

Then at this point I was hoping to reverse engineer the verifier B to come up with a poly-time verifier for Y thus contradicting the supposition that $Y \not\in NP$ similar to what the answer to this question does:
[If X is polynomial reduction to Y and Y is in NP, then X is in NP?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/128187/if-x-is-polynomial-reduction-to-y-and-y-is-in-np-then-x-is-in-np)
But that direction doesn't really work and I haven't found way to use the reasoning above to try and show that $X \not\in NP$ and achieve contradiction that way

And so this is where I am stuck. Am I missing something or am I wrong in my intuition that the statement is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) states that $\mathsf{NP}\subsetneq \mathsf{NEXP}$.

So if you consider a $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problem $A$ (for example $\texttt{SAT}$) and a $\mathsf{NEXP}$-complete problem $B$ (for example [$\texttt{SUCCINCT HAMILTONIAN PATH}$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995886800092)), then $A\leqslant_m^p B$, $A\in \mathsf{NP}$ and $B\notin \mathsf{NP}$.

Note that more simply, you can consider $A=\emptyset$ and $B$ any problem not in $\mathsf{NP}$ and the result still holds.

Comment: Ah direct counter example and so the statement is false then. Could you explain what $A = \emptyset$ means? Is A literally an empty set or is this some kind of notation for A being the halting problem (I am simply not familiar with the interpretation of $\emptyset$ when discussing $P$ and $NP$)

Comment: A problem is a set. So $A = \emptyset$ means the empty problem. It can be interpreted as "the problem where the answer is always *FALSE*".